# Reducing 'while loop' with conditions

Tags: r, control-flow

My objective, in the grand scheme of things, is to *print only the rows that have a similar/same field name without repetition*. That, is, if three rows are duplicated, print each of them only once (rather than each pairwise comparison).

A minimal dataset and library to reproduce:

```
library(stringdist)
trye <-  data.frame(names = c('aa','aa','aa','bb','bb','cc'),
                    values = 1:6,
                    id = c('row 1', 'row 2', 'row 3', 'row 4', 'row 5', 'row 6'), 
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

My expected output would be the rows that have the same/similar name (1,2,3,4 and 5):

```
trye 
#   names values    id
# 1    aa      1 row 1
# 2    aa      2 row 2
# 3    aa      3 row 3
# 4    bb      4 row 4
# 5    bb      5 row 5
```

Here are two tries that have not worked (some other modifications have thrown errors):

```
#this one prints row 1,2,3,3,5,5
i <- 1
while (i < length(trye$names)) {

  dupe <- amatch(trye$names[[i]],trye$names[-i], maxDist = 1)

  if(dupe  + 1 > 0) {
    print(trye[i,])
    duperow <- dupe + 1
    print(trye[duperow,])
    trye <- trye[-c(i), ]
    i <- i + 1


  } else {
    i <- i + 1
    trye <- trye[-c(i), ]
  }

}



# this one prints rows 1,2,4,5 which is almost correct,
# it's missing row 3 (as it shares the name with row 1 and 2.
i <- 1
while (i < length(trye$names)) {

  dupe <- amatch(trye$names[[i]],trye$names[-i], maxDist = 1)

  if(dupe  + 1 > 0) {
    print(trye[i,])
    duperow <- dupe + 1
    print(trye[duperow,])
    trye <- trye[-c(i,duperow), ]
    i <- i + 1


  } else {
    i <- i + 1
    trye <- trye[-c(i,duperow), ]
  }

}
```

Please note that the actual dataset is huge, so deleting rows to make the comparisons smaller seems (or seemed) like a good idea to me, also, the max distance in the actual set is larger than 1.

Comment: so do you want to omit the rows with a single occurrence?

Comment: something like this? `sapply(1:nrow(trye), function(x) sum(adist(trye[x,1], trye[,1])==0)>1)` ? using `adist` instead of amatch

Comment: This works for this example, so please feel free to add it as an answer and I'll accept. My actual dataset however, is 500krows, so reducing the size of the dataset with each pass is very very desired! Also, maxDist is 1 in this example, but its larger in my actual set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `adist` from base, to get a Levenshtein distance, and filter by those that have at least one match (other than themselves):

```
sapply(1:nrow(trye), function(x) sum(adist(trye[x,1], trye[,1])==0)>1)
```

If your data is very large as `adist` is expensive, you could remove all duplicates, except first and last of each:

```
trye[(!duplicated(trye$names) | rev(!duplicated(rev(trye$names)))),]
```

and add them back in afterwards. You might also want to check [openrefine](http://openrefine.org/) which is a way that might speed this up.